# Advanced pivot_longer: extract pattern in variables

Tags: r, dplyr, extract

My R df looks like this:

```
ID   CO.RT   CO.ER   SC.RT   SC.ER
1    0.19    0.06    1.24    0.09
2    0.61    0.01    0.63    0.03
3    0.43    0.02    1.31    0.09
```

I've been trying to find a way to use **tidyr::pivot_longer** to achieve the following:

```
ID   Type    RT      ER
1    CO      0.19    0.06
1    SC      1.24    0.09
2    CO      0.61    0.01
2    SC      0.63    0.03
3    CO      0.43    0.02
3    SC      1.31    0.09
```

My issue: I can only pivot RT and RT into a single "score"-column—I fail to find the right regex(?) pattern to pivot my df in the way shown above.

Here is what I tried:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(CO.RT:SC.ER),
       names_pattern = "(.+).(.+)",
       names_to=c("Type", ".value"))
```

There are many pivot_longer/names_to questions out there, however, I couldn't find the right one for my problem. Can anyone help?

*My dataset:*

```
df <- tibble(
  ID = c(1,2,3),
  CO.RT = c(0.19,0.61,0.43),
  CO.ER = c(0.06,0.01,0.02),
  SC.RT = c(1.24,0.63,1.31),
  SC.ER = c(0.09,0.03,0.09)
)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you tried, but `df %>% pivot_longer(!ID, names_pattern="(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)", names_to=c("type", ".value"))` or `df %>% pivot_longer(!ID, names_sep="\\.", names_to=c("type", ".value"))` should work. Also `pivot_longer` comes from `tidyr`, not `dplyr`

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick, I have edited the package and added what I tried. Your answers are exactly what I was looking for, would you be willing to post them as a normal answer so I can award it? Thanks for letting me know how to improve my questions, I am still new to this network and data science in general.